# Google Apps Script - how can one filter calendar events on multiple properties with advanced calendar service

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

When using the [Calendar.Events.list](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/calendar#listing_events) of Google Apps Script's advanced calendar service, how can I filter on multiple privateExtendedProperty values?

```
    var existing_events = Calendar.Events.list(calendar,{'privateExtendedProperty':'copperOpportunityId='+opportunity['id'],
                                                         'privateExtendedProperty':'copperFieldId=shoots',
                                                         'orderBy':"startTime",
                                                         'singleEvents':true
                                                        }
                                              );
```

Will not work, because the second "privateExtendedProperty" property of the filter object overwrites the first, and the API only receives the latter one.

Meanwhile the [API Documentation](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list) states

> This parameter might be repeated multiple times to return events that match all given constraints.

Comment: At Advanced Google services, when the same key is used in the query parameters, the key has an array. This is the same with the googleapis of other languages. I could know about this from them. For example, spreadsheets.values.batchGet is the same situation. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchGet) But this cannot be found in official document. So I think that your thread is useful for other users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to pass an array of property values:

```
var existing_events = Calendar.Events.list(calendar,{'privateExtendedProperty':                                                   
                                                       ['copperOpportunityId='+opportunity['id'],
                                                        'copperFieldId=shoots'
                                                       ],
                                                     'orderBy':"startTime",
                                                    'singleEvents':true
                                                   }
                                               );
```